# How to merge multiple Objects with similar keys from an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, reduce

So I have the following JSON. The result that I'm looking for is if there are multiple objects with the same site_id, to create an object which contains the site_id, an array of users, and the rest of the properties merged together.
I tried using reduce, but it's not working :D

Thank you in advance

```
{
        "response": [
            {
                "site_id": "4587c4183c312dd82309be6cdae7bbd6",
                "name": "esse",
                "lat": 82.3172,
                "lon": -30.0668,
                "company": "256090f4d3a41f34096876b71ee03694",
                "user_id": "2d3393051386426adca86c13362e6f46",
                "UserName": "Juliet44",
                "Password": "Test",
                "FirstName": "Kristy",
                "LastName": "Goldner",
                "Company": "256090f4d3a41f34096876b71ee03694",
                "Email": "Kassandra37@hotmail.com",

            },
            {
                "site_id": "4587c4183c312dd82309be6cdae7bbd6",
                "lat": 82.3172,
                "lon": -30.0668,
                "company": "256090f4d3a41f34096876b71ee03694",
                "user_id": "2f2a174f63f7e277630eb808974dfd05",
                "UserName": "Marguerite_Smith34",
                "Password": "Test",
                "FirstName": "Christian",
                "LastName": "Gerhold",
                "Company": "256090f4d3a41f34096876b71ee03694",
                "Email": "Urban.Boyer@yahoo.com",
            },
            {
                "site_id": "94fc61eee3c0d01abace7a2feb84bc4c",
                "name": "blanditiis",
                "lat": 13.3673,
                "lon": 54.3085,
                "company": "256090f4d3a41f34096876b71ee03694",
                "user_id": "3f85f1a435df6c3ca4ac944116515c04",
                "UserName": "Tyrell.Schimmel",
                "Password": "Test",
                "FirstName": "Lucius",
                "LastName": "O'Conner",
                "Company": "256090f4d3a41f34096876b71ee03694",
                "Email": "Eino.Hackett@gmail.com",
            },
        ]
    }
```

Comment: *"I tried using reduce"* ...show what you tried. Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is to help you fix **your code**. Take some time to read [ask]

Comment: can you show your desired output please

Comment: What's the difference between `site_id`, `Company`, and `company`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the rest operator is your friend. And im not shure if you really need to reduce, a simple forEach does it:

```
 var hash={}, result = [];

 response.forEach(function({site_id,...rest}){
  if(!hash[site_id]){
    result.push(hash[site_id]={site_id});
  }
  let el = hash[site_id];
  for(key in rest){
    if(el[key]){
      el[key].push(rest[key]);
     }else{
      el[key] = [rest[key]];
    }
  }
 });
```

Comment: Yes this works perfectly, I managed to work it out as you did. Thank you